# Check if any part of a string matches a given string in python

Tags: python, string

How would one check if any part of a string matches a given string.

For example, if I had the string "tyghfjsf" and wanted to check if the specific substring "ghf" was in the string, how would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: `"ghf" in "tyghfjsf"`

Answer (score 4):

Use the `in` operator:

```
>>> "ghf" in "tyghfjsf"
True
```

Answer (score 1):

`def chek_words(string, specific_string):

    l = specific_string in string

    return l`

if it returns true then specific string is in given string else not.